Finding difference between two Linux Commands
How to find the difference between rm and rmdir commands in Linux Bash Shell?

You can check man, but rmdir is only for empty dirs, while rm can apply to files and directories.

To the close voters: this is entirely on topic and certainly isn't too broad. If you feel it isn't a useful question or that it shows a lack of research, that's what downvoting is for.

Simply pasting the question into a search engine gives plenty of answers - often easier to read than the man pages.

It's unclear whether rm and rmdir are two examples, or whether you want to know the differences between these two specifically. One may ask "What's the point of rmdir if rm -r deletes directories?" On other systems, rm - remove directory entries and rmdir - remove directories.   The question then becomes "What's the difference between directory entries and directories?"  Unfortunately, the question does not really say what is sought.  The [tag:open-source] tag makes it even more confusing, because it could mean that they want the source code differences...

The answer is to check their manuals. On Linux (and UNIX) systems, you can access a command's manual using the command man. In your case, you would run man rm and then run man rmdir and compare what you see. In this case, the difference is eplained in the very beginning of the two manuals:

man rm

RM(1)                        User Commands                       RM(1)

NAME
       rm - remove files or directories


man rmdir

RMDIR(1)                     User Commands                    RMDIR(1)

NAME
       rmdir - remove empty directories



So rm can delete both files and directories (rm -r), including non-empty ones, but rmdir can only remove empty directories.

I often rm files in subdirs as I finish processing them. A rmdir cleanup step deletes empty subdirs
